# Showing Data in Rectangle on the click of circle using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I Have few circles that contain people names,I need to show their information on the click of circle in rectangle using d3.js

Below is my script

```
    var width = 960,
    height = 500;
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    d3.json("data.json", function (json) {
        /* Define the data for the circles */
        var elem = svg.selectAll("g myCircleText")
        .data(json.nodes)
        /*Create and place the "blocks" containing the circle and the text */
        var elemEnter = elem.enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ",80)" })
        /*Create the circle for each block */
        var circle = elemEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r })
        .attr("stroke", "black")
        .attr("fill", "white")
        .on("click", function () {

        var s = svg
                .selectAll("circle");
          s
    .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 100)
        .attr("y", 200)
        .attr("width", 200)
           .attr("width", 200)
        .style("fill", "red");
       });

        /* Create the text for each block */
        elemEnter.append("text")
        .attr("dx", function (d) { return -20 })
        .text(function (d) { return d.label })
    })

below is the json file:
{"nodes":[
  {"x":80, "r":40, "label":"Sam","info":"Developer"}, 
  {"x":200, "r":60, "label":"Pam","info":"Programmer"}, 
  {"x":380, "r":80, "label":"Ram","info":"Architect"}
]}
```

Circles are being drawn with names but when I click on circles nothing is happening.

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Two issues with your onclick function. First, `width` is set a second time instead of height:

```
.attr("width", 200)
.attr("width", 200)
```

Second, you're appending a rectangle to a circle:

```
    var s = svg.selectAll("circle");
    s.append("rect")
```

which isn't valid for a svg:

```
<circle r="60" stroke="black" fill="white">
    <rect></rect>
</circle>
```

Instead, the rectangles should be appended to root of the svg or a g element.

Working code:

```
    .on("click", function () {          
      svg.append("rect")
          .attr("x", 100)
          .attr("y", 200)
          .attr("width", 200)
          .attr("height", 200)
          .style("fill", "red");
    });
```

Comment: Hi Adam,Thanks a lot for your reply it worked :). Also I was trying to show data in the Rectange of that person. So I tried below:          svg.append("rect")
          .attr("x", 100)
          .attr("y", 200)
          .attr("width", 200)
          .attr("height", 200)
          .style("fill", "red")
          .text("text", function (d) { return d.info }); But it's not showing the text on rectangle, Also Is it possible to show Image and Data both in rectangle, like image of person on left and Information on right side of Rectangle. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If Adam's answer helped then you should go ahead and accept it.

Comment: how can i get the data related to that circle and show it in Rectangle that is the question.